# How to change Footer copyright in prestashop 1.7.4.2?

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Prestrashop 1.7.4.2 footer unable to change. I tried through admin panel->IMPROVE -> International->Translation-> MODIFY TRANSLATIONS under [image]

and modify button click.

[image]

Copyright content change box not showing.

How to resolve this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have made the footer content.

- In My Store I used Jewelry theme.
- Through database 'ps_htmlbanners7_slides_lang' table, I have added my desire footer content.
- Clear cache and It worked like a charm!.